# How to change state of angular ui-router website when bootstrap carousel 'next' or 'previous' button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I have a very basic angular ui router module set up for a website I am working on. It is as follows:

```
  var myApp = angular.module('main', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider){

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: './home_screen.htm'
        })
        .state('nowshowing1', {
            url: '/nowshowing1',
            templateUrl: './now_showing.htm'
        })
        .state('nowshowing2', {
            url: '/nowshowing2',
            templateUrl: './now_showing.htm'
        })
        .state('comingsoon1', {
            url: '/comingsoon1',
            templateUrl: './now_showing.htm'
        })
        .state('comingsoon2', {
            url: '/comingsoon2',
            templateUrl: './now_showing.htm'
        })
        .state('concessions', {
            url: '/concessions',
            templateUrl: './home_screen.htm'
        })
        .state('freemovies', {
            url: '/freemovies',
            templateUrl: './FreeMovies.htm'
        })
        .state('pictures', {
            url: '/pictures',
            templateUrl: './pictures.htm'
        })
        .state('contributors', {
            url: '/contributors',
            templateUrl: './contributors.htm'
        })
        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: './home_screen.htm'
        });

});
```

I have a bootstrap carousel and my ui-view inside the carousel. Right now, my website works when using my bootstrap navbar to navigate to each page, where each page is an html page, but also a 'slide' in the carousel. I want the user to be able to use the arrow buttons on the side of the screen to switch to the next and previous 'slide' or page.

I am very new to angular and angular ui router, and I have not been able to find useful documentation on how I might not only access the current, next, and or previous states in my stateProvider, but how to call the method that will access those from my html.

I tried a controller like this:

```
 myApp.controller('StateChangeCtrl', function($scope, $state){
    $scope.previousState = function(){
        console.log('Previous State!', $scope);
    }
});
```

Then tried to call previousState() onclick of the arrow buttons in the carousel, but got a not defined error.

How/where would I access the current, next, and or previous state of the website if my pages go in the order of how I declared them in the stateProvider, and then how would I call the function from html that would do that?

If I could even access the current state somewhere, I can hardcode what the next and previous states will be (I assume I'd use $state.go() to change states) because I know the order of my html pages and there are not a ton of them...